# ffmpeg frame->pts out-of-order when decode hevc

Tags: ffmpeg, pts

I try to set `pkt->pts` to 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,
but the `frame->pts` received is 0,1,4,5,3,6,2 where the `pict_type` was I, I, B, B, B, B, P.

```c
int num = 0;
pkt->pts = num++;
avcodec_send_packet(dec_ctx, pkt);
avcodec_receive_frame(dec_ctx, frame);
```

I tried to read h264 file, it is correct; and I tried to use official 'decode_video.c', it's still incorrect in hevc.

Why the `frame->pts` is not 0,1,2,3,4,5,6?